# Подключение встроенных пакетов java

Tags: java

Вот импорт, и он подсвечивается и параллельно выкидывает о

> package 'com.sun.tools.javac.util' is declared in module 'jdk.compilier, which does not export it to the unnamed module

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Flags;
import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type;
import com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager;
import com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacElements;
import com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.List;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Name;
```

Мавена и т.д. нет, один класс нужно запустить, но вот это выкидывается, есть идеи?

Comment: Я так понимаю, Java у вас 9?

Comment: @Suvitruf 10 скачал, но стоит ещё и 8

Comment: Ну, вот в этом и проблема)

Comment: В девятой яве так уже нельзя. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773519/accessing-com-sun-tools-javac-util-from-java-9

Comment: 9ую ещё скачать? с 8ой почти тоже самое происходит. Как лучше поступить тогда)

Comment: @KeyJibo или 8 использовать, или градл скрпит поправить.

Answer (score 1):

Это из-за того, что Java у вас 9+.

В градл скрипте пропишите:

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '10'
    targetCompatibility = '10'
    options.with {
        fork = true
        forkOptions.javaHome = new File ('c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10')
        compilerArgs.addAll(['--add-exports', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED'])
    }
}
```

Comment: без градла никак?)

Comment: @KeyJibo у вас Maven?

Comment: просто как бы без них лучше обойтись, если есть возможность

Comment: @KeyJibo вот тут на русском хорошая статья есть для разных типов сборок https://dou.ua/lenta/articles/problems-with-java-9/

Comment: так если я переключил на 8 версию, почему подсвечивает дальше, но уже без ошибок, просто не находит теперь

Comment: @KeyJibo вы это в настройках редактора переключили или где? Что за редактор, кстати?

Comment: Idea, да, ctrl shift alt s ==> и там переключил на нужную версию

Comment: @KeyJibo вот тут https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPjwm.jpg ?

Comment: да, я там устанавливал